# 'file too short' error on g++ when compiling .o file

Tags: c++, makefile, linker, g++, ld

Here is the error:

```
g++  -lpthread -pthread -std=c++11 -g -D_GNU_SOURCE  src/QuoridorMain.o src/Tree.o src/utility.o src/Game.o src/storage.o -o qbot
/usr/bin/ld: error: src/QuoridorMain.o: file too short
collect2: error: ld returned 1 exit status
make: *** [Makefile:12: qbot] Error 1
```

And here is the Makefile I'm using.

```
# Makefile for qbot

# Compiler options
CXX = g++ # use g++ compiler
CXXFLAGS = -lpthread -pthread -std=c++11 -g -D_GNU_SOURCE -no-pie# openmp and pthread, g for debugging


.SUFFIXES: .o .cpp
OFILES = src/QuoridorMain.o src/Tree.o src/utility.o src/Game.o src/storage.o

qbot: $(OFILES)
    $(CXX) $(CXXFLAGS) $(OFILES) -o qbot
    @echo Produced qbot executable 

clean: 
    $(RM) *.o *~


# Dependency rules for *.o files
src/Tree.o: src/Tree.cpp src/Tree.h src/utility.cpp src/Global.h
src/QuoridorMain.o: src/QuoridorMain.cpp src/Tree.cpp src/Game.cpp src/Global.h
src/utility.o: src/utility.h src/utility.cpp src/Global.h 
src/Game.o: src/Game.cpp src/Game.h src/Global.h
src/storage.o: src/storage.cpp src/storage.h
```

I'm not super good at determining what is necessary and what is cruft in a makefile, and linker errors are often my downfall. That being said, this was compiling just fine before, and the only thing that I think changed between compiling perfectly and this error is the addition of some `std::cout` statements. So I'm pretty lost as to what's up.

Perhaps relevant stuff: I'm compiling on a new computer compared to what I developed most of the code on, and was getting a `ld` related error earlier, which I fixed by adding the `-no-pie` flag. However, that made sense to me, and even removing the `-no-pie` flag now gets the same compile error about. Also: it is likely there are significant errors in the run-time of my code. Earlier I was getting segfaults or non-segfaults during runs based on whether certain `std::cout` statements are commented out or not. I was told this was a sign of major problems elsewhere, but if you could be specific as to what those problems often are, and how they would now affect compiling rather than just run-time, I'd be very appreciative. Thanks!

EDIT: At the suggestions of commenters, I have taken out all .cpp files from the .o dependency rules. I am still receiving the same error after a `make clean`. I suspect I will need to do more moving things about to make it actually work instead of just removing .cpp files, but that doesn't appear to be the direct issue at play.

Comment: Your cpp files should not depend on other cpp files. Other than that, does the problem go away  if you `make clean`?

Comment: You don't ever compile the C++ files to object files.

Comment: No, `make clean` does not help. Is there a specific best practice that helps enforce the no cpp dependencies thing? I did that a while ago and don't remember the exact reasons, but it made it work at the time.

Comment: Oh, duh. Your `make clean` does not remove the files in `src`. You should probably change that recipe to `rm -f $(OFILES)` instead. What does `make -B src/QuoridorMain.o` produce? That should unconditionally remake that file.

Comment: @Botje That is quite embarrassing. This seems to be the issue. I'm still not sure where the issue came from, or why it was working before, but it seems I haven't done a real `make clean` since the start of the project. Is there a way to mark a comment as correct? Thank you!

Comment: I'll write an answer with some other suggestions

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The core problem is that your .o file got damaged some time in the past.

The secondary problem is that your `clean` target does not actually clean up the OFILES, as it only removes `*.o`, not `src/*.o`.

```
## EDIT: removed -lpthread
CXXFLAGS = -pthread -std=c++11 -g -D_GNU_SOURCE -no-pie # openmp and pthread, g for debugging

OFILES = src/QuoridorMain.o src/Tree.o src/utility.o src/Game.o src/storage.o

## EDIT: Used $@ and $^ instead
qbot: $(OFILES)
    $(CXX) $(CXXFLAGS) $@ -o $^
    @echo Produced qbot executable 

## EDIT: fixed clean target and designated it as .PHONY, which stops Make from looking
## EDIT: for a file named "clean"
.PHONY: clean
clean: 
    $(RM) -f qbot $(OFILES) *~

## EDIT: Removed .cpp files from dependency list.
## EDIT: Keeping the similarly-named cpp files, even though they are redundant.
# Dependency rules for *.o files
src/Tree.o: src/Tree.cpp src/Tree.h src/Global.h
src/QuoridorMain.o: src/QuoridorMain.cpp src/Global.h
src/utility.o: src/utility.cpp src/utility.h src/Global.h 
src/Game.o: src/Game.cpp src/Game.h src/Global.h
src/storage.o: src/storage.cpp src/storage.h
```

Answer (score 0):

You wrote that the object files depend on your C++ files, but you didn't include a rule for making the object files from your C++ files. You can see that you never invoke `g++` with `.cpp` file arguments. What I think is happening, is `make`, not seeing a rule, just makes empty object files.

Comment: ... except `make` has built-in rules for compiling cpp files into object files.

Comment: @Botje Ah. Well I generally don't use those. May be due to the .h files in there. Could be stopping the implicit rule from being generated.

Comment: I added an edit to add that I have removed all .cpp files from the .o dependency rules. In addition, this was compiling just fine yesterday with the exact (butchered) dependency rules you see in the post. I was aware it was not best practice, but it did at least seem to do what I expected.

Comment: @EamonCollins You shouldn't give `*.h` files to the compiler. Those are just to be included, not to be made into object files. Check that maybe? Also don't remove `*.cpp` files from dependency lists for `*.o` files. The commenter @Botje was saying not to have `*.cpp` files depend on `*.cpp` files, which you don't seem to have. Just add a rule yourself to create the object files.

Comment: @Anonymous1847 no, the implicit rule is of the form "%.o: %.cpp". What OP did was simply add extra *dependencies*, not extra *inputs*.